# Creating a menu item that links to its parent

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I've been searching low an high to do this. I want to create a normal menu item programatically that links to its parent. Similar to the concept of default menu task, but just a normal menu item. Has anyone ever done this?

I want something that I can do with one of the drupal hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a new menu-item, that has the same *path* as its parent.

Comment: are you referring to this by using the UI? I'm wanting to do this programmatically.

Comment: Yes, this was meant via the UI. The Drupal API has no way to define parent-child menu relations, other then trough their path. So I am not aware of clean and simple way to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
$items['parent'] = array(
    'title' => 'I am parent',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => 'get_parent',
    'access arguments' => array('access parent'),
    'type'      => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);

$items['parent/child'] = array(
    'title' => 'I am child link of parent',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => 'get_children_for_thisparent',
    'access arguments' => array('access children of parent'),
    'type'      => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

This should do the trick :)

Comment: @gokul-n-k I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting with this. You've simply done a normal menu structure using hook_menu, and I have not found any drupal function or property yet that tells drupal menu that the child item path is the same as its parent path. I'm trying to achieve default menu items exactly the same as default menu tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to place it under Main menu,

```
    $item['form_example'] = array(
        'title' => 'Example menu',
        'description' => 'This is an example menu item',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'page callback' => 'custom_function',
        'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    );

    return $item;
```

You will then get the menu item under Main menu (clearing cache). The trick is adding a key 'menu_name'.

To get the menu_name please open the menu administration page, and click on 'edit menu' on any root menu. URL will be like 'SITE_URL/admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu/edit'. Look at the url segment just before the last(here main-menu).

For the second case you might want to place it under Home of main menu. The code is.

```
$item['form_example'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example menu',
    'description' => 'This is an example menu item',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'page callback' => 'custom_function',
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    'plid' => 218,
);

return $item;
```

Here, I have added a key plid to associative array, it is the mlid of the menu item('Home' here) for which it will be a child. For this case it will be child of Home menu.

To get the mlid you have to do the same as described above, goto menu administration page and click list links and then click edit on the menu item, e.g. SITE_URL/admin/structure/menu/item/218/edit, thus you can get the mlid and thus its done.

Note. If you change this menu hierarchy or other settings from back-end, you will always have reset option to reset it, and after resetting it will behave like described in the code.